# Trying to create a hash with word | value, but my value always comes up as 1

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do an exercise where you take a phrase (which I defined as the variable text), and then split up the text into separate words (words=text.split). Then, I create a new hash called frequencies, and try to give each word a value, like 1,2,3 so that I can sort them by the value later. But when I run this, every word is given the value of 1. I want it to be 1 and 2 and 3 and so on.

```
puts "please enter a phrase"
text=gets.chomp

words=text.split

frequencies=Hash.new(0)

words.each do |word|
    frequencies[word]+= 1
end

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |a, b| b }
frequencies.reverse!
```

This is how they are being valued. Why are they all "1"?

```
please enter a phrase
 Top of the morning to you
[["you", 1], ["to", 1], ["morning", 1], ["the", 1], ["of", 1], ["Top", 1]]
```

Comment: Well each word appears only once in your sentence, so 1 seems like the correct result. Which one did you expect to have values 2 and 3, and why?

Comment: This is working fine. I get the following: `please enter a phrase
; a a a b b; [["a", 3], ["b", 2]]`. Your sample output doesn't seem to reflect any problem, unless you're actually only entering each word once. Without seeing your sample input, it's impossible to guess.

Comment: I see.. thanks so much, appreciate it.

Comment: If anyone has a board they can recommend for beginners, can you let me know? I'm not sure where the best place is to post my questions. The downvotes make me think maybe my questions are a little too simple for this board. I'm only a couple of weeks into really learning Ruby, so I still run in to a lot of problems that may annoy  ppl here.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I think the reason for the downvotes is that your code appears to be perfect, so it's not clear to people what the question actually is. Questions about problems that either don't exist or can't be reproduced tend to get downvoted since there isn't much that anyone can learn from reading them and it's unclear how they can even be answered.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I was following a tutorial but what happened was I was expecting a different output, but it was because my understanding of what we were trying to accomplish was incorrect. It got cleared up in my mind after I read the comments here. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're counting the frequencies of the words — the number is how many times the word was found in the text. Since each word in your sample text is unique, the answer is 1 for all words. If you want to assign each word an incremented value, you can do something like:

```
frequencies = Hash[words.zip(1..words.count)]
```

But I am not sure that's what you actually want, since you actually called it "frequencies," and that is what you're actually counting in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it as below :-

```
puts "please enter a phrase"
text=gets.chomp

words=text.split

frequencies = Hash.new(0)

words.each do |word|
    frequencies[word]+= 1
    frequencies.default += 1
end

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |a, b| b }
p frequencies.reverse!
```

[`Hash.new(default)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new) - *. If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.*

When you would set the default value, then when you would do `Hash#[]`, you will get the default value, if the *key* you are trying to access, not still added to your *hash*. Now when you doing `frequencies[word]+= 1`, it means `frequencies[word] = frequencies[word] + 1`. Thus first time, `frequencies[word]` on the *RHS*, default value* is being return, whis has then incremented by `1` and got to the `word` hash for the key `word`. *But you are not changing the **default** value at all.* `"you"`, `"to"`, `"morning"`.. are different keys, to which you assigning value with each iteration.

> I want it to be 1 and 2 and 3 and so on.

Then, with every iteration, you need to change the *default value*, to meet your need. That can be done using [`Hash#default=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D).